# VB.Net: Using and addressing buttons in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, controls, tablelayoutpanel

Hi I have this TablelayoutPanel setup currently in my program to create a grid of buttons that will later correspond to a specific column and row:

```
'****INITIALISES TABLE LAYOUT INTO FORM******
    Dim ColCount, RowCount As Integer

    'Later change so that values are automatically calculated
    ColCount = 5
    RowCount = 5

    '*********Copy and pasted from site as example, CHANGE LATER*******
    Haztable = New TableLayoutPanel
    Haztable.AutoScroll = True
    Haztable.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Haztable.ColumnCount = ColCount
    Haztable.RowCount = RowCount
    For rowNo As Integer = 0 To Haztable.RowCount - 1
        For columnNo As Integer = 0 To Haztable.ColumnCount - 1
            'Dim ctrl As Control = New Button
            'ctrl.Text = String.Format("{0} {1},{2}", ctrl.GetType().Name, columnNo, rowNo)
            'ctrl.Size = New Size(20, 20)
            'Haztable.Controls.Add(ctrl, columnNo, rowNo)
            Dim buttonname As String
            buttonname = "B" & columnNo & rowNo
            Dim button As Control = New Button
            button.Size = New Size(70, 20)
            button.Name = buttonname
            button.Text = buttonname
            Haztable.Controls.Add(button, columnNo, rowNo)
            AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf buttonname_Click
        Next
    Next
    Me.Controls.Add(Haztable)
    Call buttonfind()
```

And this all works, creating a grid of buttons, much like the layout of an excel spreadsheet.

The buttons are named according to their XY position (e.g. the button in (1,1) would be called "B11") but the problem is I can't seem to work out how I can address these buttons i.e

*If B(X.Y) is clicked then save boolean value that button at X,Y is pressed.

It would be great to have one algorithm to scan and check if any buttons have been pressed instead of using "Select Case" for each button. 
I would just create the buttons in the designer but for my full code i'm going to need 1000+ buttons and that seems an inefficient way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttonname_Click should have a Sender object which is the Button that you Clicked just cast it to a Button and check the name then.

```
Private Sub buttonname_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    Select Case btn.Name
        Case "B11"
            'Do something
        Case "B12"
            'Do Something esle

            '...........
    End Select

End Sub
```

---

Based on your last statement see if this works you may need to build an Array or a List if you need to reference the Text elsewhere in your Program

```
Private Sub buttonname_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    If btn.Text = "H" Then
        btn.Text = "M"
    ElseIf btn.Text = "M" Then
        btn.Text = "L"
    ElseIf btn.Text = "L" Then
        btn.Text = ""
    Else
        btn.Text = "H"
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: @Joe the Select Case is a way to avoid a large convulated If Statement. you may want to look at the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: You should create a new class and inherit Button and include variables like ClickCount, Row, Column etc...

Comment: @Mark That is very useful thank you. Is there a way to combine all these "Select Case" statements into 1 statement that just checks if any button has been pressed and if so, where it was (X,Y) and what the button text was. Sorry for my lack of understanding.

Comment: @Joe are you just wanting to increment the Text on the Button or are you wanting to do something else. if only the Text you do not need the select Case you already have a reference to the Button so you can just increment it at that time.

Comment: @Mark Excuse my ignorance again, these buttons are clicked by the user, and with each click the text in the button changes from H to M to L and then blank and then the next click starts that cycle again . There will be 1020 buttons in the final program and I need to know the value of the button text for every button in the TablelayoutPanel. I could use your Select Case algorithm but for 1020 buttons that may be inefficient. Is there a way of checking all these buttons for their text values without replicating that select case algorithm 1020 times? Thank you .

Comment: @Mark got it! I use Case "B11" to "B44"

Comment: @ Mark That is exactly what I needed for that part, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have add clicked event and handle each of them by using their row and column number. Make yourself a new button first so that you can access row and column numbers with spending **no effort** to parse column and row numbers from the controls name:

```
Public Class NewButton
    Inherits Button
    Public Row, Column, ClickCount as Integer
End Class
```

Now create and handle:

```
Public Class Form1
    Sub addbuttons()
        Dim newbut As New NewButton
        newbut.Name = "B12"
        newbut.Row = "1"
        newbut.Column = "2"
        'and other properties...
        AddHandler newbut.Click, AddressOf clicked
        Me.Controls.Add(newbut)
    End Sub
    Sub clicked(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim x As NewButton = DirectCast(sender, NewButton)
        If x.Column = 2 And x.Row = 1 Then
            x.ClickCount += 1
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```